# Is it possible to collect all elements with same class name by getElementBY Class()?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to collect all elements with same class name by `getElementBYClass()`?

```
<div class="a"> date1</div>
<div class="a"> date2 </div>
```

Now I need to collect date1 and date2 and put it in array.

Comment: did you have a look at jQuery? http://jquery.com/

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in order to better format your question next time.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `document.getElementsByClassName("a");`

But [this isn't compatible with IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname)

If you want to be compatible with IE8, I suggest the use of [jQuery](http://jquery.com), which enables `$('.a')` which returns a collection of all elements with class "a".